# Tag synonyms: wake-on-lan and wol

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

I just finished re-tagging all (20-odd) questions with [wol](/questions/tagged/wol) as [wake-on-lan](/questions/tagged/wake-on-lan) (many of them had both tags).

Please mark [wol](/questions/tagged/wol) as a synonym of [wake-on-lan](/questions/tagged/wake-on-lan).

Comment: Next time, you can just request to have it merged into the other tag. No need to retag manually.